# How to implement Lax-Friedrich flux splitting with WENO scheme

Tags: fluid-dynamics, eigenvalues, hyperbolic-pde, conservation, weno

I'm working on modeling a shock wave using the Euler equation with an advanced Equation of state and the fifth order WENO scheme. The equation are set up on the form:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial U}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial F(U)}{\partial x}  = 0
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
U = \begin{bmatrix}\rho\\ \rho v\\E\end{bmatrix}, F(U) = \begin{bmatrix}\rho v\\ \rho v^2 + p\\v(E+p)\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
I've formulated the WENO scheme, but have yet to get it to work. What I find difficult to implement is the Lax-Friedrich Flux splitting. Specifically determining the $\alpha$ in the equation:

\begin{equation}
f^{\pm} = f(U) \pm \alpha U
\end{equation}

I do know that $\alpha = \max \left|\frac{\partial f(U)}{\partial U}\right|$, but for what index range of $U$ does the equation strech when i want to determine:

\begin{equation}
\hat{f}_{i+1/2} = \hat{f}_{i+1/2}^+ + \hat{f}_{i+1/2}^-
\end{equation}

Comment: The $\hat{f}$ denotes the numerical formulation. In regards to the Equation of state, it is a somewhat complicated EOS adapted to the LJS fluid. I utilize a function which computes the temperature and pressure based on the internal energy and density. This does makes it difficult to determine analytical eigenvalues, compared to the ideal case.

Comment: I solve the temporal discretization using 5th explicit Runge Kutta with the programmingfunction solve_ivp() in python. What I specifically want, is to compute the $f^{\pm}$ in order to utilize the WENO scheme, but descriptions in litterature of $\alpha$ doesn't indicate the range of $U$. The spatial formulation is correct.

Comment: Ah got it, so your semi-discrete formulation reads $$\frac{\mathrm d \boldsymbol{u}} {\mathrm d t } = \frac{1}{\Delta x} \Big( \hat{ \boldsymbol{f}}_{i-1/2}  - \hat{ \boldsymbol{f}}_{i+1/2} \Big)$$?

Comment: That is correct, where the $\hat{f}_{i\pm1/2}$ values are computed using the WENO scheme, with the splitted fluxes ($\hat{f}^{\pm}$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean with Lax-Friedrichs the *local* Lax-Friedrichs or *Rusanov* scheme [[1]](https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/fs2014/other/n_dgl/chap8.pdf), [[2]](https://www-m16.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/M16/Allgemeines/NumMethHyp/Num-Meth-Hyperbolic-Systems.pdf) where the wave speeds (left & right-going) are given by the maximum eigenvalue $\lambda_\max := \max_i | \lambda_i(\boldsymbol{U}) | \in \sigma\Big( \boldsymbol{F}'(\boldsymbol{U}) \Big)$ where $\sigma$ denotes the spectrum of the Jacobian $\boldsymbol{F}'(\boldsymbol{U})$.

Note that the Rusanov / Local Lax Friedrich scheme is an *approximate Riemann solver*: For a conservation/balance law with Riemannian initial data, it provides an approximate solution. **In particular, the scheme depends only on the trace (face / edge) values at the cell boundary / interface**. In fact, it does not care how you got them - i.e., the scheme is agnostic whether you used simply the cell average value, a linear approximation with limiters or in your case the fifth order WENO scheme to reconstruct the face / trace values.

To finally answer your question, you need to take only the trace values $\boldsymbol{U}^-, \boldsymbol{U}^+$ into account at a certain face.
Then,

$$\alpha := \max \bigg\{ \max_i \big \vert \lambda_i (\boldsymbol{U}^-) \big \vert \in \sigma\Big( \boldsymbol{F}'(\boldsymbol{U}) \Big) \Big \vert_{\boldsymbol{U}^-} , \max_i \big \vert \lambda_i (\boldsymbol{U}^+) \big \vert \in \sigma\Big( \boldsymbol{F}'(\boldsymbol{U}) \Big) \Big \vert_{\boldsymbol{U}^+} \bigg\}. $$
In other words at each face $i$ you jest need the trace values $\boldsymbol{U}_i^+, \boldsymbol{U}_i^-$. In that case, your numerical flux (I think you lack the factor if $1/2$ in your formulation and confused the signs) is given by
\begin{align}
\hat {\boldsymbol{f}}_{i+1/2}& = \frac{1}{2} \Big( \hat {\boldsymbol{f}}_{i+1/2}^+ + \hat {\boldsymbol{f}}_{i+1/2}^- \Big) =\frac{1}{2} \Big( F(\boldsymbol{U}_i^+) - \alpha \boldsymbol{U}_i^+ + F(\boldsymbol{U}_i^-) + \alpha \boldsymbol{U}_i^- \Big) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \Big( F(\boldsymbol{U}_i^+) + F(\boldsymbol{U}_i^-) + \alpha (\boldsymbol{U}_i^- - \boldsymbol{U}_i^+ \Big) \end{align}

Comment: Thank you! A couple of follow-up questions: So by interface of an index $i$ I only take the maximum approximate eigenvalue between the $i \pm 1/2$ values? Do you have any advice for computing the jacobian i.e. approximate values for values connected to the EOS?

Comment: More precise, you take the maximum of the absolute values of the eigenvalues of the Jacobian $\frac{\mathrm d \boldsymbol{F}}{\mathrm d \boldsymbol{U}} = F'(\boldsymbol{U})$ which is evaluated at both sides of the interface $i+ 1/2$. Based on your reconstruction / interpolation method you have the value $\boldsymbol{U}_{i+1/2}^- $ on the left of the $i+1/2$ cell boundary and $\boldsymbol{U}_{i+1/2}^+ $ on the right. The Jacobian / eigenvalues (if analytically known) are evaluated at this states.